# Remove rows when cells are equal

Tags: r, duplicates, subset, rows

I have a table:

```
df <- read.table(text=" 
a    b    5
a    a    2
c    a    3   
d    d    2    
a    a    1    
b    d    2   ")
colnames(df) <- c("Gen1","Gen2", "N")
```

I would like to remove the rows when Gen1 = Gen2. 
For example I would get for this example:

```
result <- read.table(text=" 
a    b    5
c    a    3     
b    d    2   ")
colnames(df) <- c("Gen1","Gen2", "N")
```

I tried with duplicated but duplicate is working per rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
subset(df, Gen1!=Gen2)
```

Or `filter` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    filter(Gen1 != Gen2)
```

#### data

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.character)
```

Comment: or 
`df[!(duplicated(df[c("Gen1","Gen2")]) | duplicated(df[c("Gen1","Gen2")], fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Comment: Akrun, that works if the strings are as.character ;)

Answer (score 0):

For large dataset you can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Gen1!=Gen2,]
```